# Aligned equations inside of TikZ node.

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, vertical-alignment

How can I create a tree node with an aligned math equations inside?

```
\begin{align}
\end{align}
```

doesn't work

```
\begin{minipage}{100}
  \begin{align}
    ...
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}
```

Gives a lot of margin and I don't want to manually tune 100.

\nodepart from shapes tikz library seems to be overkill and doesnt do
the alignment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You could use an `aligned` environment with inline math inside nodes, their size is automatically calculated. Here's a small example with such a node in a tree:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={rectangle,draw}]
\node {Example:}
  child {node {%
  $\begin{aligned}
     a &= bx + c\\
     a+b &= d +1
  \end{aligned}$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great! it works.
But why align doesn't?

Comment: align is displayed, set off normal text and centered. Here it requires a minipage environment or \parbox, so it needs specifying a width. At least for the centering.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Zarko in the comments, the `text width` option to the node already defines a minipage. Thus, the `minipage` environment is superfluous unless you want the minipage width different than the node width.

---

I know this is old, but, for future reference, if you want to number your equations or really want to use an `align` environment, you may place it inside a `minipage` and specify both the node `text width` and minipage width properties to whatever works for you.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % These are needed to remove the vertical space around above and below
    % the align and flalign environments
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}

    \node [rectangle, draw] (example) {Examples:};
    \node [rectangle, draw, right=1cm, text width=4cm] (eq1) at (example.east) {
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{align}
                x + y &= 1 \\
                x - 2y &= 1
            \end{align}
        \end{minipage}
    };
    \node [rectangle, draw, below=0.5cm, text width=4cm] (eq2) at (eq1.south) {
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{flalign}
                x + y &= 2& \\
                x - 2y &= 2&
            \end{flalign}
        \end{minipage}
    };
    \draw [->, line width=1pt] (example) -- (eq1);
    \draw [->, line width=1pt] (example) |- (eq2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This example also includes `flalign`, since I believe it looks better than `align` when the node has borders.

[image]

Comment: when you define text width of node, the node behavior as `minipage`, consequently use of `minipage` in your example` is superfluous. the same result you will obtain without it.